Как использовать переменную в качестве столбца в SQL. Python
Мне нужно чтобы столбец подставлялся вместе со значением в цикле и заносился в БД
def data_save():
    a = []
    b = ['number', 'info', 'info2','way', 'car_c', 'car_w', 'time']
    for (i,b) in zip(new_list, b):
        a.append(i.get("1.0", END))
        conn.execute('INSERT INTO BASES (b) VALUES (?)', (a))
        print(a,b)
        a.clear()


Нашел решение, использовав следующий метод подстановки
def data_save():
    a = []
    for i in new_list:
        a.append(i.get("1.0", END).strip())
        a = [x.replace("\n", " ") for x in a]
        if len(a) == 8 :
             print(a)
             conn.execute('INSERT INTO BASES (number,info1,info2,way,car_c,car_w,time,note) VALUES %r;' % (tuple(a),))
             a.clear()


Да, название столбца нельзя интерполировать через execute, к сожалению.
